# how can I remove app/window from sharing session in rdpcomapi?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, rdp

I am working with remote desktop sharing in WPF - visual studio. My requirement is to hide specified application. I have windows for that application. I used "windows" variable below code.

```
            while(windows.MoveNext()){
                IRDPSRAPIWindow win = windows.Current as IRDPSRAPIWindow;
                win.Shared = false;
            }
```

please help me, Or suggest me any other way to hide/remove application from sharing session.

Thanks,
suribabu

Comment: @have you got the answer this is balu?

Comment: yeah, balu. Finished.

Comment: then post u'r answer may be it'l helps some one.

Comment: we have to set property called "Enabled" of "applicationfilter" to true.

Comment: How did you include "AxRDPViewer" to WPF toolbox? in other words how to include the Viewer version of RDPCOMAPILib in WPF app.